# How would I go about making this tail-recursive?

Tags: scheme

I have this code:

```
(define (prog1 x y)
    (let ([rel (related x y)])
      (cond
        [(null? rel) (list x)]
        [else (cons x (map (lambda (d) (prog1 (neighbour d) y)) rel))])))
```

What I want to do is try and make it tail-recursive. I know that I need to do something like:

```
(define (prog1 x y)
  (prog1-iter x y `()))

(define (prog1-iter x y acc)
  (...
   ))
```

But I am unsure how to go from my code to this code... I think it's because the original has a map in it and I am unsure how to incorporate this into an `prog1-iter`. Could someone point me in the correct direction!

Comment: It might be helpful to see the original algorithm, even better if it's well-known and an imperative solution exists. That will make it easier to transform to a functional, tail-recursive implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tail-recursion is easy to write for things that are inherently iterative. Your function potentially calls itself many times, so it is not going to be simple. Nevertheless, any program can be made iterative (e.g. your computer is a giant iterative machine), so it can be done.

First of all, your function is not *directly* recursive (i.e. `prog1` does not directly call itself). Rather, `prog1` calls `map`, which then calls the lambda you gave it (perhaps multiple times), which then calls `prog1`; so it is indirect. The call to `map` is not a tail call; the call from `map` to the lambda is certainly not a tail call (it may need to call it more than once); and the call from the lambda to `prog1` is a tail call.

Therefore, I am not sure what exactly you require when you ask it to be "tail-recursive". Do you want each call in the chain of calls from `prog1` to itself to be a tail-call? Or do you want to make every call in the program a tail call? There exist "tail-recursive" versions of `map`, but they are only "tail-recursive with respect to calls from `map` to `map`, and not calls to the mapping function, so they are not useful for your case.

The general method to make every call in a program a tail call is called [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Basically, every function takes an additional function argument, the "continuation". Instead of making a non-tail call to a function, you instead make a tail call to it, and pass it a continuation specifying how to process the results of the function call. Basically, the continuation would encompass the "rest of" the original function after the non-tail call, and it would take in the "return result" of the original non-tail call as an argument. I will leave it as an exercise how to convert your program to CPS.